# Check if readLine is blank, but don't read a line

Tags: java, io

I have a while loop that performs while readLine != "". The problem is, it reads the line and moves on to the next one, which is not what I want. What I need is either for it to test whether the line is blank without moving on to the next line, or for it to go back to where it was before reading it.

Thanks in advance.

```
while (fileReader.readLine() != "") {
     String readLine = fileReader.readLine();
}
```

Comment: Please specify your components you're working on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You provided very little information, so I guess your problem is that you don't have the actual string inside your loop body. Correct me if I'm wrong.

To address this problem, you could do:

```
String line;
while(((line = reader.readLine()) != null) && !("".equals(line)))  {
  System.out.println("line: "+line);
}
```

Comment: how it stops when blank line occured

Comment: replace `!=null` with `!=""`. either ways ANDing both would be better

Comment: @blacktrance The difference between mine and your solution is that you use `readLine()` twice, so the you only read every second line. Inside your loop you have to use `line` which is the current line

Answer (score 1):

In the while loop itself Store the line in a variable

```
String line="";
while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
  //Perform your operations
}
```